# how to get type of generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I am not able to determine the type of generic parameter in my application. The situation is like the code below. When i get a generic `ICollection`, I need the Count. If not, i need to work on the single object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Cat
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cat cat1 = new Cat { Id = 1 };
            Cat cat2 = new Cat { Id = 2 };
            ICollection<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
            cats.Add(cat1);
            cats.Add(cat2);
            TestMethod<ICollection<Cat>>(cats);
            TestMethod<Cat>(cat1);
        }
        public static void TestMethod<T>(T parameter)
        {
            //if parameter is <ICollection<Cat>>, get count of cats?
            //else if (T is Cat), get id of the cat?
        }
    }
}
```

I put the question wrongly, it can be cat, dog, mouse or anything else. I dont know what it is and I dont need to either. I was trying the below code and getting casting error.

((ICollection)parameter).Count;

I just need the count if it is an ICollection of any objects.

Many thanks for all the answers.

Comment: I can not understand what you want? please provide what output you expect?

Comment: You dont need a generic method for this purpose. Just turn the parameter into object. Using generics for this is defying the purpose of generics.

Comment: In the generic parameter i am sometime getting an ICollection of something. I just need the count if it is a collection of some objects.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a swiss-army method that should be called `YoullNeverGuessWhatIllDo()`. Since your method behaves *completely differently* for collections and non-collections, why not create two methods, one of which accepts an `ICollection<T>` and provides the collection behaviour? If you're writing a generic method that *cannot act generically given any type parameter that meets it's type constraints*, stop and take a hard look at whether it should be generic in the first place.

Comment: I am thinking about adding another generic optional parameter, so if users give ICollection of cats for generic variable T, then pass cat for the optional generic parameter U. Does not seem good. My method implements an interface and it seems i cannot overload based on generic constraints.                                     public static void TestMethod<T, U>(T parameter)
{
            int cnt;
            if (parameter.GetType().IsGenericType)
                cnt = ((ICollection<U>)parameter).Count;
            //else
                //work with T as cat}

Comment: Why can't we cast a collection of cats to a collection of objects?

Comment: Because a *collection* of `object`s can have *anything* added to it. So if it turns out it was meant to be a collection of `cat`s, anyone still accessing it as such would be surprised to enumerate it and discover that item #6 is not in fact a `cat` (or something derived from it) but instead a `bookcase`.

Comment: Also, you can [edit] your question to improve it, rather than putting code here in the comments, where it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetType - Gets the Type of the current instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern Matching to check types, like so:

```
switch (parameter)
{
    case ICollection<Cat> collection:
        var count = collection.Count;
        // Do something
        break;

    case Cat cat:
        var id = cat.Id;
        // Do something
        break;

    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No cats.");
}
```

However, if you just want to know what `T` is, you can use `typeof(T)` to get a `System.Type` object for the generic type used when calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of parameter(T) like below and then check:

```
var type = parameter.GetType();
if(type == typeof(List<Cat>))
{
 // do something
}
else if(type == typeof(Cat))
{
 //do something
}
```

and for your information, run time type of cats in case of below statement :

```
ICollection<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

is of type:

```
List<Cat>
```

not

```
ICollection<Cat>
```

If you want to check and validate for compile time types, you may need to use explicit cast on run time type while checking.

Other alternate is simply use "is" keyword for type checking like below:

```
if(parameter is ICollection<Cat>)
{

}
else if(parameter is Cat)
{

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int result;
        if (parameter is ICollection<Cat>)
            result = (parameter as (ICollection<Cat>)).Count;
        else if (parameter is Cat)
            result = (parameter as Cat).Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a situation where you want to use generics, as this is not the purpose of generics.

You have two options here.

Either you make two methods like this:

```
public void TestMethod(Cat cat) {...}
public void TestMethod(ICollection<Cat> cats) {...}
```

Or if you really need this kind of general purpose method then use object as a parameter.

```
 public void TestMethod(object obj) 
 {
    Cat cat = obj as cat;
    if(cat != null)
    { 

        return;
    }
    ICollection<Cat> cats = obj as ICollection<Cat>;
    if(cats != null)
    {

    }
 }
```

But even then, this is only a good idea if you are using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may it hep you

```
class Cat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat { Id = 1 };
        Cat cat2 = new Cat { Id = 2 };
        ICollection<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
        cats.Add(cat1);
        cats.Add(cat2);
        TestMethod<ICollection<Cat>>(cats);

        TestMethod<Cat>(cat1);
    }
    public static void TestMethod<T>(T parameter)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ICollection<Cat>))  //if (parameter is ICollection<Cat>)
        {
            ICollection<Cat> cats = parameter as ICollection<Cat>;

            //Count your cats in count variable
            int count = cats.Count;
        }
        else
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Cat))  // if (parameter is Cat)
        {
            Cat cat = parameter as Cat;

            //Get id of your cat in id variable
            int id = cat.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @san, view answer might be it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your TestMethod can be wriiten as below...

```
public static void TestMethod<T>(T parameter)
{
    // Check if it is a ICollection of any object
    if (parameter is ICollection && parameter.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
        var itemCount = ((ICollection)parameter).Count;
    }
    else
    {
        // write your else logic
    }
}
```